# Fork() in Threads

Tags: operating-system, pthreads, fork

Does `fork()` duplicate only the calling thread or all threads?

What I think is that the fork will create a duplicate of all the functions written after `fork()`. Am I right? I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork`ing in a thread duplicates only the *calling thread*. There's no "duplicate all the functions" at run time but only copying (of the entire address space -- including thread constructs such as mutexes, conditional variables etc) the calling thread into another process. It's generally complex to use `fork` in a thread and you could run into problems very easily while managing the state of pthread resources (mutexes, cond variables etc).